# ember-cli merge several js into vendor.js without calling app.import for each js-lib

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a way to import several js-libs into vendor.js without the need to call app.import for each import.

Similar to the new Funnel Copy Style.

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults);

  app.import();
  app.import();

  var Assets = new Funnel('bower_components/webix', {
      srcDir: "codebase",
      include:["fonts/*","webix_debug.js","webix.css","skins/flat.css"],
  });

  return app.toTree(Assets);
};
```

Comment: The Funnel Copies the files only, but i want the same style to import all js or css into vendor.css or vendor.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no. You need to app.import each file, one at a time. You are of course, welcome to make an RFC here by opening a pull request to suggest your idea: https://github.com/ember-cli/rfcs